# Access denied with Azure Automation / o365 Exchange connection

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, exchange-server

this is my first post. I created an account specifically for this question because I'm absolutely confounded.

Basically I'm having the exact same problem as what I found here, but there was no solution posted.
https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/8sz7s8/can_anyone_help_access_denied_with_azure/

I'm receiving this error when attempting to connect to Exchange online when using a service account from my automation account. I think the problem may also be that my $credential variable is not passing into my $session variable, but I can't think of any reason why that would be happening.

```
New-PSSession : [ps.outlook.com] Connecting to remote server ps.outlook.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Trouble
```

If I run this locally, I don't get any issues. I have logged into Exchange with this service account to confirm the password works. I've checked that it has Exchange admin access. I know that the credentials and permissions are fine. Oddly enough, I was using this same script on another automation account in an old subscription. I copied the settings exactly (or at least I thought I did) and figured I could just re-use this runbook.

My connection call is pretty much exactly like the one in the link I shared.

```
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'Admin-ExchangeOnline'
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 'https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/' -Credential $credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

    Import-Module (Import-PSSession -Session $session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber) -Global
```

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/get-azureautomationcredential?view=azuresmps-4.0.0): _This PowerShell command for Azure Automation will no longer be supported on 01/23/2020. The Azure Service Management model is deprecated for Azure Automation, and will be disabled on that date. Please use the commands which support the Azure Resource Management model in [Az.Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/az.automation)._

Comment: Wow I feel really silly for not noticing that! I'll give the new cmdlet a try. Thanks so much!

Comment: I hope you get it fixed with the new commands. Sorry I cannot test this out myself.

Comment: So now I can create a credential object by using

`$credential = Get-AzAutomationCredential -ResourceGroupName 'resource-group' -AutomationAccountName 'AccountName' -Name 'Credential-Asset'`

But now I am receiving a new error when I attempt to pipe it into my $Session variable.

`New-PSSession : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. userName`

Looks to me like there is parameter name within the object that the cmdlet doesn't recognize. I'll look into how I can reconcile that.

Comment: Figured out the issue. Real stupid. I had entered the username for the credential asset incorrectly. Once I did this my original script worked. However, just so people are aware, my attempt to connect using the get-AzAutomationCredential cmdlet did not work. I was able to create a $credential object with the cmdlet, and it appears to work correctly, but I think the structure of the object is incompatible with the traditional means for connecting to Exchange Online.

Comment: I think this calls for you to write this out as answer, so other people may benefit. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. Real stupid. I had entered the username for the credential asset incorrectly. Once I did this my original script worked. However, just so people are aware, my attempt to connect using the get-AzAutomationCredential cmdlet did not work. I was able to create a $credential object with the cmdlet, and it appears to work correctly, but I think the structure of the object is incompatible with the traditional means for connecting to Exchange Online.